# Determine File Path in Java

Tags: java

I have inherited a code base. The code is loading a file called "my.properties". That file is being loaded via the following code:

```
public SomeConstructor(String filePath) {
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("my.properties");
  ...
}
```

The code works. My problem is, the code I inherited has "my.properties" files all over the place (I'm talking 50 places). So I can't figure out which "my.properties" is actually being loaded. How can I print out the full path of the file loaded into the `FileInputStream`?

Comment: If just for determination, construct a `File`.

Comment: file.getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do: `System.out.println(new File("my.properties").getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 0):

The File.getAbsolutePath() will give you the full complete path name (filepath + filename) of a file.

```
File file = new File("my.properties");
System.out.println("Path : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this link may help you out.[click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/fileinputstream_getfd.htm)

The FileInputStream has a method called getFD() which gives you an object that describes the file. hope this is what your looking for.